# TeamCity Integrated with Xcode Projects (BUILD RUNNER)

Tags: xcode, teamcity, xcodebuild

Im trying to get TeamCity to work with the github server for our xcode projects.

I've got the git server working and now i'm stuck at the Build Runner Settings.

i downloaded the teamcity-xcode plugin from http://github.com/orj/teamcity-xcode

and moved it into the ~/.BuildServer/plugins folder.

is there any kind of tutorial how to set up TeamCity for xcode projects ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok so i've finally figured it out after hours of headache.
I posted a tutorial if anyone else needs help with the same problem and needs to save a day or two. :)

http://alexandern17.posterous.com/

Comment: Sorry for not maintaining my plugin.  Jetbrains are now providing their own. See the TeamCity wiki for details: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Xcode+Runner

Comment: @Alex your link is broken :(